# Link To Library with C and C++ Bindings

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, g++

I am trying to determine if it is possible to link against a linux library with c and c++ bindings. I have an existing c++ project which is broken down into several libraries. I would like to extend these libraries with C bindings so that I can use them with cgo.

I am aware of how to mix c/c++ with extern "c" syntax. The problem that I have is in daisy chaining libraries. I've created a sample project which demonstrates my question:

https://github.com/Shelnutt2/c_cpp_linker_test

In this project we have hello.c, world.cpp both of which are built into a library called libwords . I can link libwords to libhelloworld without an issue. The problem occurs when trying to build main.cpp, which wants to call a c and c++ functions from libhelloworld (and thus the linked libwords)

Due to the linking differences of C++ vs C the main executable can not find the hello function

```
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `hello'
```

Is it possible to link against the same library in this manner or do I need to break c-bindings into their own wrapper library?

In this example project I used shared libraries, but I'm open to static linking if that is possible.

Comment: There is no language C/C++. C does not support `extern "C"` for obvious reasons. Not clear what you want to accomplish. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf The 'language' C/C++ is the intersection of C and C++. FWIW, ANSI C89 is almost a true subset of C++, in K&R book for ANSI C89 all examples compile with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @ErikAlapää: That's plain nonsense! 1) C is C11, ANSI-C is long gone. Leave the body burried. 2) Same for C++, which is C++14 (with a major diversion with C++11). 3) Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics Try `static const int i = 5; int a[i];` in both, similar `auto int i = 5, a[i];`. 4) Whoever tells that C++ is a superset of C does not know at least one of the two languages not well enough to write much more than a "Hello World"; at least not any production code.

Comment: @Olaf, if anything, you are writing nonsense. What I stated are facts, not opinion. A huge part of C out there still does not use even C99. No other two languages I know of are as similar as ANSI C89 and C++. And I know both C and C++ very well. Try compiling anything from the K&R book and you will see how C-like C++ is.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Successful compilation of trivial code is an accurate test of languages being the same?  [So German and English are the same language now?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaXigSu72A4)

Comment: @AndrewHenle K&R is not trivial code. And there is good reason the C and C++ std comittees have tried to keep the languages as similar as possible, without hampering the development of either C or C++.

Comment: @ErikAlapää K&R is **not** C according to standard. And it **is** a collection of trivial code indeed. You should move on to modern C an C++.

Comment: @Olaf I use modern C++. And note that I never said that ANSI C89 was the latest C standard. It is just the dominant way the majority of all C code in the world was written.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Even MISRA moved on to C99. And you are even wrong for C90.

Answer (score 1):

You should link your application with both libraries. The exports are not transitive.

```
main: main.o libhelloworld.so
    $(CXX) $< -L'$(CURDIR)' -lwords -lhelloworld -o $@


> gmake
c++ -Wall -g -O -fPIC -DC_LINK_TEST=1   -c -o helloworld.o helloworld.cpp
cc -Wall -g -O -fPIC -DC_LINK_TEST=1   -c -o hello.o hello.c
c++ -Wall -g -O -fPIC -DC_LINK_TEST=1   -c -o world.o world.cpp
c++ -Wall -g -O -fPIC -DC_LINK_TEST=1    -shared hello.o world.o -o libwords.so
c++ -Wall -g -O -fPIC -DC_LINK_TEST=1    -L'/usr/home/me/c_cpp_linker_test' -lwords -shared helloworld.o libwords.so -o libhelloworld.so
c++ -Wall -g -O -fPIC -DC_LINK_TEST=1   -c -o main.o main.cpp
#c++ main.o libhelloworld.so -o main
c++ main.o -L'/usr/home/me/c_cpp_linker_test' -lwords -lhelloworld -o main

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:`pwd` ./main
c gives us: hello
cpp gives us: hello world

>
```

Otherwise there is no problem with linking both C and C++ calling conventions, as the name mangling is different.

(never mind the change g++ to c++ - I use clang)